# Using Multiple Database in Spring boot

Tags: mysql, database, spring

I encounted a problem when I wanted to work between two database, I wanted to use the table 1 in database 1 and the table 2 in database 2, I tried so many ways, but all seems not work.

```
spring.datasource.primary.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.primary.username = root
spring.datasource.primary.password = xxxx
spring.datasource.primary.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.datasource.secondary.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.secondary.username = root
spring.datasource.secondary.password = xxxx
spring.datasource.secondary.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

above is my application.properties. Then I used @Primary setting spring.datasource.primary as the primary database in config file.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User {
    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "phoneid")
    private String  phoneid;
}
public interface UserDAO extends CrudRepository<User, String> {
    public User findByPhoneid(String phoneid);
}
```

I want to connect to database spring.datasource.primary and use the table User in it.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Favorite_Restaurant")
public class FavoriteRestaurant {
    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "favorite_restaurantid")
    private int favoriteRestaurantId;
}
public interface FavoriteRestaurantDAO extends JpaRepository<FavoriteRestaurant, Integer> {

public List<FavoriteRestaurant> findAll(Sort sort);
}
```

I want to connect to database spring.datasource.secondary and use the table FavoriteRestaurant in it.

However when I Autowired UserDAo and FavoriteRestaurantDAO in My Service, It seems just like it autowired both userdao and favoriterestaurantdao from primary database. How can I inject FavoriteRestaurantDAO from secondary database!!!!! help!!!!!!

Comment: Please check this link to see if it helps http://xantorohara.blogspot.in/2013/11/spring-boot-jdbc-with-multiple.html

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use several datasources you need to have several persistent unit configurations.

I will assume that you've got `datasourceA` and `datasourceB` to configure.

We have one configuration class for each of our persistent units. The listing contains the class for `datasourceA` (you will have to copy and adjust the configuration for `datasourceB`).

It's also a good idea not to mix the entities from different persistent units.
So we have separated them based on the package. We have created an empty class
`SpringRootPackageMarker` so that it tells spring which packages to scan.

**Note!** the `SpringRootPackageMarker` class is used in both `@EnableJpaRepositories` and in `getDatasourceAEntityManagerFactoryBean` method

So this is our way how to do it:

```
@DependsOn("transactionManager")
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackageClasses = SpringRootPackageMarker.class,
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "datasourceAEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager")
public class DatasourceAPersistenceUnitConfiguration {


    private static final String DATASOURCE_A_PERSISTENT_UNIT_NAME = "datasourceAPU";


    @DependsOn("transactionManager") // for unit tests
    @Bean(name = "datasourceAEntityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean getDatasourceAEntityManagerFactoryBean() {
        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setPersistenceUnitName(DATASOURCE_A_PERSISTENT_UNIT_NAME);
        factory.setDataSource(getDatasourceA());
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(getDatasourceAJpaVendorAdapter());
        factory.setPackagesToScan(SpringRootPackageMarker.class.getPackage().getName());
        Properties jpaProperties = getDatasourceAJpaProperties();
        factory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDatasourceA() {

        DataSource datasource = null;
        // prepare datasource A;

        return datasource;
    }


    private JpaVendorAdapter getDatasourceAJpaVendorAdapter() {
        final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

        //custom configuration for datasource A

        return vendorAdapter;
    }


    private Properties getDatasourceAJpaProperties() {
        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();

        //custom properties

        return jpaProperties;
    }
}

}
```

if you plan to inject the entityManager into your application you'll have to do it this way:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName= DatasourceAPersistenceUnitConfiguration.DATASOURCE_A_PERSISTENT_UNIT_NAME)
private EntityManager manager;
```

Comment: Thanks,I finally know what is going wrong!!!  I missing a @EnableAutoConfiguration above the config class, I will put my solution later

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved this problem by adding @EnableAutoConfiguration above my config class

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "datamodel.dao", entityManagerFactoryRef = "localEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "localTransactionManager")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAutoConfiguration  ///the key to make spring boot know your config!!!!!!!!!!!!!
public class MainDataConfig {
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.main")
@Primary
public DataSource localDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean
@Primary
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localEntityManagerFactory(final EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
    return builder.dataSource(localDataSource()).packages("datamodel.domain")
        .persistenceUnit("mainPersistenceUnit").build();
}

@Bean
@Primary
public JpaTransactionManager localTransactionManager(@Qualifier("localEntityManagerFactory") final EntityManagerFactory factory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(factory);
}
}
```